# .load loading content in a box inside the div, rather than just filling the div

Tags: jquery

essentially i would just like the text of the loaded content. I've been researching jquery functions but can't find the right one. couldn't get $.get() to work. Both the preexisisting div and loaded  scrap have an id of "content".
jquery:

```
 $(function() {
        $('#header a').click(function() {
            $('#content').empty();
            $('#content').load(this.href);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

html:

```
<div id="header" class="ui-corner-all ui-buttonset">
         <a title="index" href="index.php" ><span>home</span></a>
         <a title="code" href="code.php" ><span>code</span></a>
         <a title="design" href="design.php" ><span>design</span></a>
         <a title="illustration" href="illustration.php" ><span>illustration</span></a>
         <a title="writing" href="writing.php" ><span>writing</span></a>
         <a title="links" href="links.php" ><span>links</span></a>
         <a title="about" href="about.php" ><span>about</span></a>
         </div>

<div id="contentspace" class="body ui-corner-all">
</div>
```

a loaded page:

```
<??>
<div id="content">
<title>illustration</title>
<h2>illustration</h2>
</div>
<??>
```

Comment: Are exactly are you trying to do? server your markup and you will be helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both the preexisisting div and loaded scrap have an id of "content".

i didnt understand the question well, but you should not have the identical `id`s

```
$(function() {
 $('#header a').click(function() {
 $('#content').empty();
  $.get(this.href,function(data){
    $("#content").append($(data).wrap("<div class='box'/>"));
  });
   return false;
 });
});
```

Comment: i'll try giving them different names.

Comment: it will wrap the retured data into a `div` before inserting into the `#content` div

Comment: thanks. this does work, but i was unfocused in my original question and went with something using .load().